# Javascript/Regex: Expression works in one environment and not another

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to only allow alphanumeric entry or these characters:'()-_. (with the "." included)

Using regexpal.com I entered this regular expression: `[^a-zA-Z0-9()\.'\-\_ ]`

It is correctly identifying * and @ as a match. What's baffling is that I have that same exact expression in my javascript on an .aspx page and it is not catching * or @. I have confirmed that is indeed entering that function and that the expression evaluates. Here is that code:

```
  $(".validateText").keyup(function (e) {
          var matchPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9()\.'\-\_ ]";
          var regEx = new RegExp(matchPattern);
          console.log("Regex: " + regEx + "\nValue of " + e.target.id + " is: " + e.target.value);
          if (regEx.test(e.target.value)) {
              console.log("Found invalid data.");//I don't get here with @ or *
              var failingChar = e.target.value.length - 1;
              e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, failingChar);
          }

  });
```

Comment: Try `console.log(matchPattern)`. You forgot to escape your backslashes.

Comment: Looks like I'm getting this: [^a-zA-Z0-9().'-_ ] from logging out matchPattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using string literals to define regexes, use regex literals.

```
var regEx = /[^a-zA-Z0-9()\.'\-\_ ]/;
```

String literals interpret backslashes as escape characters, so they need to be escaped. Regex literals don't require this.

As per Bergi's suggestion, you wouldn't even need to escape all those characters.

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9().'_ -]/
```

You could probably even use the general `\w` character.

```
/[^\w().' -]/
```

Comment: No need to escape `.` and `_`

Comment: Works great. Will accept when I can. While we are on the subject, is it possible to put say the regex you provided into a variable and call test? As opposed to directly saying /[^a-zA-Z0-9().'_ -]/.test(foo)? I have two different regex scenarios I need to do, and provide the correct one based on the element's ID.

Comment: I think you could. Note it's *not* a string literal, it's a regex literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
var matchPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9()\\.'\\-\\_ ]";
```

Would work.